# how to create an onscreen keyboard for a program in java eclipsee

Tags: java, swing

For my school project i need to create a bank simulator.so as a first step i am supposed to show an on screen keyboard when a button is clicked on the keyboard that value should go to the text boxes.I am totally blank. i tried i could create the keyboard. its in a different frame.so i do not  know how to retrieve data from it when the buttons are clicked on it.please help guys.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class BankSimulator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JTextField username = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField password = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField name = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField setPassword = new JTextField(5);
    JLabel userlbl = new JLabel("Username");
    JLabel passlbl = new JLabel("Password");
    JRadioButton option1 = new JRadioButton("Basic Account");
    JRadioButton option2 = new JRadioButton("Saver Account");
    JRadioButton option3 = new JRadioButton("Super Account");
    JButton logbtn = new JButton("Log In");
    JButton regbtn = new JButton("Register");
    JButton showkeyboard = new JButton("showkeyboard");
    JButton createbtn = new JButton("Create Account");
    JButton[] btn1 = new JButton[10];
    JButton[] btn2 = new JButton[10];
    JButton[] btn3 = new JButton[9];
    JButton[] btn4 = new JButton[7];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankSimulator bm = new BankSimulator();

    }

    public BankSimulator() {
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(850, 700);
        setTitle("Bank Simulator");
        username.setBounds(350, 150, 130, 20);
        add(username);
        password.setBounds(350, 180, 130, 20);
        add(password);
        option1.setBounds(440, 180, 130, 20);
        option2.setBounds(440, 210, 130, 20);
        option3.setBounds(440, 240, 130, 20);
        add(option1);
        add(option2);
        add(option3);
        option1.setVisible(false);
        option2.setVisible(false);
        option3.setVisible(false);
        name.setBounds(440, 150, 130, 20);
        add(name);
        name.setVisible(false);
        setPassword.setBounds(440, 123, 130, 20);
        add(setPassword);
        setPassword.setVisible(false);
        userlbl.setBounds(288, 150, 130, 20);
        add(userlbl);
        passlbl.setBounds(288, 180, 130, 20);
        add(passlbl);
        logbtn.setBounds(341, 220, 150, 30);
        add(logbtn);
        createbtn.setBounds(435, 270, 150, 30);
        add(createbtn);
        createbtn.setVisible(false);
        logbtn.addActionListener(this);
        regbtn.setBounds(341, 260, 150, 30);
        add(regbtn);
        regbtn.addActionListener(this);

        showkeyboard.setBounds(341, 270, 150, 30);
        add(showkeyboard);
        showkeyboard.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                showkeyboard();
            }

        });
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void showkeyboard() {

        String nos = "1234567890";
        String alphabet = "abcdefghij";
        String alphabet1 = "klmnopqrs";
        String alphabet2 = "tuvwxyz";

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.setSize(586, 205);
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel myPanel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel myPanel2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel myPanel3 = new JPanel();

        for (int i = 0; i < nos.length(); i++) {
            btn1[i] = new JButton(nos.substring(i, i + 1));
            myPanel.add(btn1[i]);
            btn1[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    keyboardButtonPressed();

                }
            });

            for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++) {

                btn2[i] = new JButton(alphabet.substring(i, i + 1));
                myPanel1.add(btn2[i]);

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < alphabet1.length(); i++) {
                btn3[i] = new JButton(alphabet1.substring(i, i + 1));
                myPanel2.add(btn3[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < alphabet2.length(); i++) {

                btn4[i] = new JButton(alphabet2.substring(i, i + 1));
                myPanel3.add(btn4[i]);
            }

            JPanel outer = new JPanel();
            outer.add(myPanel);
            outer.add(myPanel1);
            outer.add(myPanel2);
            outer.add(myPanel3);
            myFrame.add(outer);
            myFrame.setVisible(true);

        }

    }

    public String keyboardButtonPressed(char a) {

        String alreadyDisplayed = username.getText();
        String toDisplay = alreadyDisplayed + btn1[i].getText();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == regbtn) {
            username.setVisible(false);
            password.setVisible(false);
            logbtn.setVisible(false);
            userlbl.setVisible(false);
            passlbl.setVisible(false);
            option1.setVisible(true);
            option2.setVisible(true);
            option3.setVisible(true);
            name.setVisible(true);
            setPassword.setVisible(true);
            regbtn.setVisible(false);
            createbtn.setVisible(true);

        }

    }

}
```

btn[i].getText() is not working saying the 'i' cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: It's kind of complicated, but basically, you want to implement an observer pattern which can generate events from the keyboard to your other views telling them that some key was pressed

Comment: ok..but for now can u sort out the issue with the gettext() thing..

Comment: `i` is already defined in the outer `for-loop`

Comment: so if we create an other for loop inside the method will that do..

Comment: So long as the variable has been previously defined within the context your creating it, yep

Answer (score 1):

So, your basic problem is one of context...

```
for (int i = 0; i < nos.length(); i++) {
    //...
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++) {
        //...
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet1.length(); i++) {
        //...
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet2.length(); i++) {
        //...
    }
```

Basically, `i` is already defined in the outer loop, so you can't re-use it